# Noob looking for a Lua script for a primary mouse button

Tags: lua, mouse

Ok, a Lua script that does the following...
When the Primary Click AND Secondary click is held down then the "w" key is pressed.

Friend who is set is his Crysis (original) ways.

I can add a Lua in the scripting part of the profile for the game.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service, we are here to help people solve problem in their code not create code from a specification.

Comment: @Kizzy - Is it a script for logitech mouse?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a freelancer, but that doesn't mean I code for free xD
I'll set you on the right path tho (assuming this is Roblox)

```lua
local mouse = game.Players.LocalPlayer:GetMouse()

local rmb = false
local lmb = false

mouse.Button1Down:Connect(function() lmb = true end)
mouse.Button1Up:Connect(function() lmb = false end)

mouse.Button2Down:Connect(function() rmb = true end)
mouse.Button2Up:Connect(function() rmb = false end)

mouse.KeyDown:Connect(function(key)
   if key == "w" and rmb and lmb then 
      -- wave
   end
end)
```